# Transpose Table Change Log Format to Show Max and Min dates

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

I want to restructure a table into a different format. I'm stuck and have unfortunately run out of ideas.

The table shows what emails were removed from a dataset on any given day and which was added in its place (See TABLE DATA below).

I want to format the result to show for any given email, what was the min date it was added, and the max date it was removed. This will make it easier to query the change log.

Here is my table and needed output! Any suggestions or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
select  t1.ID, t1.emailAdded 
        , min(t1.date) as Min_DateAdded 
        , max(t2.date) as Max_DateRemoved
from tablename t1
left join tablename t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID and t2.emailRemoved = t1.emailAdded
group by  t1.ID, t1.emailAdded
```

Comment: T1 and t2 are just alias for your table , I had to join table with itself and the way I could distinguish them was by giving them alias

Comment: Worked for me, I had to change t1.emailAdress on the last and first line to t1.emailAdded.  I swapped out the t1 and t2 references on line 2 & 3 to t1.date, t2.date - And it works as intended now. Thank you so much! GOAT